# Health probe says the endpoints (Azure Container Instances) are degraded

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I have set up a health probe to ping Azure Containers from my load balancer so that requests are forwarded to only healthy nodes. However, I am getting "Degraded" status despite the containers being up and running. I am aware this has got to do with the reponse the health probe gets from the IP Address but I cannot figure out what changes do I need to make to my container settings to ensure that it works as expected

Comment: Do you have more questions in my reply? If the reply is helpful or others can benefit from it, you may accept it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

For Azure load balancer [backend pool management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/backend-pool-management), there are two ways of configuring a backend pool:

```
Network Interface Card (NIC)
Combination of IP address and Virtual Network (VNET) Resource ID
```

You could deploy your ACI into a VNet then add the IP address in the backend pool, then you can deploy load balancer rules and health probe for your backend ports. You could configure the appropriate health probe type for your backends. Read Load [Balancer health probes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview#types)

For example, I have an application that exposes port `8000` within the container in a VNet.

**Load balancer rule**
[image]
**Health probe**
[image]

Comment: I have the exact thing in place, my issue is that the container is not a webapp so the health probe always returns "degraded" status. Is there anything I can add to my container to make it 'healthy" in the eyes of health probe?

Comment: How do you configure your health probe? Do you use [TCP probe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview#tcpprobe) to match backend container application?

Comment: What is your container? How do you access your container as normal? I think if you expose a port within your container, then you can access your container with <protocol>:// host:port/path, so you can configure your health probe to match the TCP flow. Load Balancer health probes originate from the well-known IP address  168.63.129.16 and must not be blocked for probes to mark up your instance.